# TypeError: Method called on incompatible receiver undefined

Tags: javascript, browser, promise, typeerror

My attempt to modify the standard built-in method `then` (see below) is throwing the following error:

`TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver undefined
    at then (<anonymous>)
    at Promise.then`

**Implementation (Runtime: Browser)**

```
(function() {
  console.log(this.Promise);
  const oldThen = this.Promise.prototype.then;
  this.Promise.prototype.then = function() {
    console.log('modification');
    return oldThen(arguments);
  };
})()

Promise.resolve(1).then(fv => {
  console.log(`Promise.resolve().then(..): `, fv);
});
```

Any idea what is going on here?

---

**EDIT:**

Binding `this` to the global object via arrow functions, does not seem to work either:

```
(function() {
  console.log(this.Promise);
  const oldThen = this.Promise.prototype.then;
  this.Promise.prototype.then = () => {
    console.log('modification');
    console.log(this.Promise); // this is now the global object
    return oldThen(arguments[0]);
  };
})()

Promise.resolve(1).then(fv => {
  console.log(`Promise.resolve().then(..): `, fv);
});
```

Comment: Looks like you are not passing your arguments into the new function argument at any point

Comment: @stmfunk Got it, I can use apply to pass the arguments on. Is there a way with rest, spread or destructuring, where we can just pass all arguments onto another function (without apply)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `oldThen` with the correct `this`:

```
return oldThen.apply(this, arguments);
```

You also need to pass the arguments directly, not wrapped in an array.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate on why `this` is wrong? I see that within the modified function, `this.Promise.prototype.then` is equal to `Promise.Promise.prototype.then`, and not `window.Promise.prototype.then`. Is that why it breaks? I will try to change it to an arrow functions, thus binding this to the outer lexical context (global object).

Comment: There is only one `then()` function.  Your problem is that it needs the correct value of `this`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Oh, so is the problem that `then` uses `this` internally? I am struggling to see what `this` points to in my EDITed example above, and what it should point to, inside `then`. I mean, in my arrow function, `this` is the global object. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Magnus if you are monkey-patching a method on a class-like object, it's a good assumption that they might need `this`. When you take a reference to an objects function, it loses it's reference to 'this'. Generally whenever I need something like this, I grab a reference to the 'old' function using the 'bind' method.

Comment: @Evert Thank you. It seems like the `this` value it needs is `Promise.prototype`. But passing `Promise.prototype` directly does not work. Hmmm

Comment: @Magnus: No; it needs the _actual_ `Promise` instance you're calling it from.  Otherwise, how do you expect it to know what to do?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I think I got it: `Promise.resolve(..)` returns a new "promise object" prototype-linked to `Promise.prototype`, where `then()` resides. If `then()` uses `this` internally and `then()` is called by the new "promise object", `this` values in `then()` are intended to refer to the calling object, which is our new "promise object". `then()` uses `this` most likely because it needs access to one or more properties inside the new `promise object`. Is that right?

Comment: @Magnus: Yes; just like any other class.